# Can't seem to get my string stripper to work correctly in c++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Question I have is I am trying to strip out all "%" of a string called "workorder" and for some reason it's not working any help would be very much appreciated!

```
example:

String ^ workorder = "%QW1234%12%3"
with the below code I want it to spit out the workorder string like so = "QW1234123"
```

## HERE IS MY CODE

```
private: System::Void workorder_text_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         String ^ workorder;
         workorder = workorder_text->Text;

         //I CANT USE WORKORDER STRING FOR wO string for some reason....

         string wO(workorder);

         char bad_chars_wo[] = "%";
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(bad_chars_wo); ++i)
         {
         wO.erase (std::remove(wO.begin(), wO.end(), bad_chars_wo[i]), wO.end());
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a real need to mix `System::String` and `std::string` objects here (as in, mix CLI strings and C++ strings)?

The simplest solution to your problem is to use the methods provided by `System::String`:

```
auto workorder = workorder_text->Text;
workorder = workorder->Replace("%", String::Empty);
```

If you really need a `std::string` for later processing, you can *marshal* the `System::String`:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

```
auto wO = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(workorder);
```

See the [docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).